# how to change php img with another php img using onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, onclick

I have an img that I added to the page using php - from DB.
I would like to change it to another img from the DB based on 'onclick' meaning I would like to change the img in the tag I created before.

Here is the code of the object I would like to change

```
<?php
    include("dbAccess.php" );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bigImg_202 where id=6"; //query string
    $result = $connection -> query($sql);
    if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<img id="mainPants" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
        }
    }   
?>
```

Here are the img I would like to click that it would change

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_smallImg_202"; //query string
    $result = $connection -> query($sql);
    if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['id'] == 5){
                echo '<img id="pBlack" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
            }
            if ($row['id'] == 7){
                echo '<img id="pPink" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
            }
            if ($row['id'] == 8){
                echo '<img id="pRed" onclick="changeImage(this)" src="' . $row['img'] . '"/>';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And here is what I tried to do

```
<script>
          function changeImage(img) {
            var newImg = document.getElementById('mainPants');
                        <?php
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bigImg_202"; //query string
                        $result = $connection -> query($sql);
                        if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
                        // output data of each row

                        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
                              switch (img.id) {
                                  case 'pBlack':
                                      {
                                        if($row['id'] == 5);
                                             newImg.src= $row['img'];
                                      }
                                    break;
                                  case 'pPink':
                                    {
                                        if($row['id'] == 7);
                                             newImg.src= $row['img'];
                                      }
                                    break;
                                  case 'pRed':
                                  default:
                                      {
                                        if($row['id'] == 8);
                                             newImg.src= $row['img'];
                                      }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                        mysqli_close($connection);
                    ?>
          }
        </script>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What is it - `newImg.src`, `img.id`? Do you understand that php doesn't support dot-notation?

Comment: You have to use an `onclick` handler in JavaScript to replace the URL of the image. Once the page gets to the browser the PHP that generated it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: sorry didn't copy it well.. it's in a script

Comment: I want the new img to come from DB too is that possible?

Comment: awww... where was that canned question explaining the difference between server side and client side?

Answer (score 1):

woah woah, you cannot do this from server right away. you need either

- assign all the possible images into some javascript variable and then handle that, **or**
- make a new php script that will be called via `ajax` on frontend side via javascript.

since your php script and the question doesn't make it seem like you have coded this stuff for too long, i think option 1 will be a lot simpler for you

```
<?php
    include("dbAccess.php" );
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_bigImg_202"; //query string
    $result = $connection -> query($sql);
    $all_images = array();
    if ($result -> num_rows > 0) {
        // assign the imag
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($all_images, $row['img'] );
        }
    }   
    ...
```

at this point, the variable `$all_images` will have a list of all of your images from the database, now you can push this information to the front-end, for example, like this (not really sure about your project sctructure/framework, so i will just echo it away i guess)

```
    ...
    echo("<script type='text/javascript'>".
      "var all_images=[".implode(',', $all_images)."];" //implode functino glues variables from an array into a string via a glue you define. we use comma for the javascript array
    ."</script>");
    ...
```

now you can define a **javascript** function that set an img to a another image that is present in the all_images **javascript** array. maybe like this

```
var current_image_index_in_use=0; //global variable
function changeImage(dom_element){
    //loop through image indices
    current_image_index_in_use++;
    if(current_image_index_in_use>=all_images.length){
       current_image_index_in_use=0; 
    }

    var image_to_use=all_images[current_image_index_in_use];

    dom_element.src = img.src=image_to_use;
}
```

now you are ready to write this to your `<img />`

```
<img onclick="changeImage(this)" src="..some initial image.."/>
```

if you would like to change the id of the image as well, you could change `all_images` so it would have not only image src information but also its relevant id. i strongly advice against doing `if ($row['id'] == 5){$id="pPink" ...` like you do in your example. rather, create a new column in the database that will have this information stored and return it automatically into a two dimensional array, like

```
        while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($all_images, array($row['img'], $row['my_dom_id']); );
        }
```